# Unable to get css to work in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

This is a beginner question.  I am not able to get my css to work in Google App Engine.

My YAML file has the following

```
application: helloworld27dec
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets/
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
```

My python script (helloworld.py) has the following code:

```
import webapp2, cgi, re, datetime

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render(self,htmlfile):
        with open(htmlfile, 'r') as content_file:
            if (content_file):
                content = content_file.read()
                return content

    def get(self):
        self.response.write(self.render('test2.html'))


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

my html file (test2.html) is as follows:

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> My Title </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

my css (style.css) is in the folder /stylesheets, and is as follows:

```
<style> 
h1{
color: red; 
background: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

I cannot see the css work (i.e. red font and yellow background).  I have tried many things, but looks like I am making some very fundamental mistake.

This is what I get in the logfile

*INFO     2014-01-09 18:09:30,532 module.py:617] default: "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -*

I would greatly appreciate some help / clarification on what mistake I am making here.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong: 304 is Not Modified, in other words you will use a cached version.

Comment: Try adding `default_expiration: "0d 0h 1m"` to your app.yaml in order to decrease caching period. Take care though on the effects it brings on production

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I tried adding the default_expiration: "0d 0h 1m". Still cannot get the css working.  Frustrating, because it seems so simple and works if I put the css inline in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `style.css` file should not have any HTML tags at all. Change it to something like this:

```
h1 {
  color: red; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

You would include your css within the `<style></style>` tag only if you have inside your HTML file but not when on separate CSS file.